# How to provide an implementation for a given class using DI in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

Consider that I have 2 modules called A and B.

Let's say I have this class. It doesn't really "belong" to any module since it's a plain old Typescript class rather than an `Injectable.`

```
class Greeter {
  constructor(private greeting: string) {}

  greet(name: string) {
    console.log(`${greeting}, ${name}!`);
  }
}
```

Cool. Then, let's say module A exports a component that injects a `Greeter` instance.

```
@Component({ ... })
class GreetingComponent {
  name: string;

  constructor(private greeter: Greeter) {}

  greet() { this.greeter.greet() }
}
```

Nice. Now let's say module B has a service that extends the `Greeter` class. Module B imports module A.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class GentleGreeterService extends Greeter {
  constructor() {
    super('Hello');
  }

  greet(name: string) {
    super.greet(name);
    console.log('How are you doing?');
  }
}
```

Cool. Now, whenever I use `GreetingComponent` in module B, I expect a `GentleGreeterService` instance to be injected. However, I get no instance at all, but rather `NullInjectorError: No provider for Greeter`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers) in the official docs - I'm sure they'll explain it better than me.

Long story short - you only have a provider for `GentleGreeterService` but not for `Greeter`. You can add a provider (i.e. on module level, but also on component level) that will provide a `Greeter` but using some other class (or resolve it in other way, e.g. using a factory):

```
providers: [{provide: Greeter, useClass: GentleGreeterService}]
```

Comment: I see. The thing is I'm providing the service in one module and injecting it in another. I mean: module A needs to inject the service in `GreetingComponent`. Module B then provides a `Greeter` instance (using the snippet you provided) and imports Module A. I expected the instance provided by module B to be injected in module A's component, but I get a NullInjectorError instead.

Comment: I think I could use a factory that returns the right service based on the route's URL but that would be wacky. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776198/angular-injecting-different-service-implementation-to-a-child-module

Comment: I didn't fully read your modules setup, but the same solution still applies - I've quickly put up a stackblitz - hope it refelcts your issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvtjps

Comment: Thank you my friend, this works like a charm. You aren't *that* newb after all.